# Piecewise exponential model - how to fit

Tags: maximum-likelihood, survival, nonparametric, hazard

I'm trying to go through the following paper: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aos/1176345693

it covers the piece wise exponential model for modelling hazard rates in a non-parametric manner. First, equation (2.3) says -

$L(l) = \sum_{i,j} l_{ij} I_{ij} - \sum_{ij} t_{ij} e^{l_{ij}}$

Equation 2.6 then says -

$l_{ij} = \alpha + \sum_k \beta_k x_j^k $

but this makes it seem like $l_{ij}$ will be the same for all $i$ (each time step). So, the hazard rate for each individual will then become constant across all time intervals, which is surely not what we want. Am I missing something?

Also, the model doesn't seem to treat samples that were observed failures and censored ones differently, which it should.

Assume all symbols in section (2) of the paper except, the censored survival times will be $s_j$ instead of $t_j$ (and corresponding $s_{ij}$, etc.). How might I modify equations 2.3 and 2.6 to take the $s_{ij}$ into account as well?

Answer (score 5):

You need to transform your data to a suitable format and then fit a Poisson GLM or GAM (example below).

First you need to partition the follow-up in $J$ intervals with interval borders $(\kappa_{j-1}, \kappa_{j}], j = 1,\ldots, J$.

Then create pseudo observations $\delta_{ij}\in \{0,1\}$, such that 
$$\delta_{ij} = 
  \begin{cases}
    1, &\text{ if } t_i \in (\kappa_{j-1}, \kappa_j] \wedge \delta_i = 1\\
    0, &\text{ else }
\end{cases}
$$

and offsets $o_{ij} = \log(t_{ij})$,
  where $t_{ij} = \min(\kappa_j-\kappa_{j-1}, t_i-\kappa_{j-1})$.

That is, $\delta_{ij}$ indicates if subject $i$ had an event in interval $j$ and $t_{ij}$ indicates how much time subject $i$ spent in interval $j$.

You only include intervals in the data that were visited by subject $i$, thus right-censored observations have $\delta_{ij}=0\forall j$.

For further reading see here: https://adibender.github.io/pammtools/
especially the articles section, especially [data-transformation](https://adibender.github.io/pammtools/articles/data-transformation.html) and 
[basic modeling](https://adibender.github.io/pammtools/articles/basics.html).

Here is an example with **R**:

```r
## install the pammtools package for data transformation and example data
# install.package(pammtools)
library(pammtools)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'pammtools'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter
library(survival)

# load example data
data(tumor)
head(tumor)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 9
#>    days status charlson_score   age sex   transfusion complications
#>   <dbl>  <int>          <int> <int> <fct> <fct>       <fct>        
#> 1   579      0              2    58 fema… yes         no           
#> 2  1192      0              2    52 male  no          yes          
#> 3   308      1              2    74 fema… yes         no           
#> 4    33      1              2    57 male  yes         yes          
#> 5   397      1              2    30 fema… yes         no           
#> 6  1219      0              2    66 fema… yes         no           
#> # … with 2 more variables: metastases <fct>, resection <fct>

## transform to piece-wise exponential data (PED)
ped_tumor <- as_ped(Surv(days, status) ~ ., data = tumor, cut = seq(0, 3000, by = 100))
# the interval column indicates the interval, ped_status indicates the status
# in the respective interval
filter(ped_tumor, id == 1) %>% head() %>% select(1:8)
#>   id tstart tend  interval   offset ped_status charlson_score age
#> 1  1      0  100   (0,100] 4.605170          0              2  58
#> 2  1    100  200 (100,200] 4.605170          0              2  58
#> 3  1    200  300 (200,300] 4.605170          0              2  58
#> 4  1    300  400 (300,400] 4.605170          0              2  58
#> 5  1    400  500 (400,500] 4.605170          0              2  58
#> 6  1    500  600 (500,600] 4.369448          0              2  58

# Fit the Piece-wise-exponential Additive Model (PAM) instead of PEM
pam <- mgcv::gam(ped_status ~ s(tend) + age + sex + complications,
  data = ped_tumor, family = poisson(), offset = offset)
summary(pam)
#> 
#> Family: poisson 
#> Link function: log 
#> 
#> Formula:
#> ped_status ~ s(tend) + age + sex + complications
#> 
#> Parametric coefficients:
#>                   Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
#> (Intercept)      -9.376532   0.329410 -28.465  < 2e-16 ***
#> age               0.023187   0.004971   4.665 3.09e-06 ***
#> sexfemale         0.138748   0.105822   1.311     0.19    
#> complicationsyes  0.676899   0.106833   6.336 2.36e-10 ***
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Approximate significance of smooth terms:
#>           edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value   
#> s(tend) 3.546  4.397  16.02 0.00417 **
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> R-sq.(adj) =  -0.0553   Deviance explained = 2.82%
#> UBRE = -0.63053  Scale est. = 1         n = 8206

# compare to Cox
cox <- coxph(Surv(days, status)~age + sex + complications, data=tumor)
cbind(coef(pam)[2:4], coef(cox))
#>                        [,1]       [,2]
#> age              0.02318703 0.02305014
#> sexfemale        0.13874846 0.13583326
#> complicationsyes 0.67689876 0.67046324
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Focusing on the R code, I'm confused about which variables generated by as_ped to exclude for the gam call. It seems that id, tstart and tend are excluded but only tend and offset are used by the gam call. Is that correct?

Comment: @Tripartio in the simplest case, you have the new status variable `ped_status` as outcome and `tend` or actually `s(tend)` will be used as feature to model the baseline hazard. `offset` has to be included as offset to obtain correct likelihood. Other then that, you just include covariates. In more complex settings e.g. recurrent events, you might want include id (e.g. via random effect). In case of left truncation you might want to include `tstart` to check for independence of left-truncation and event times.